# Program isn't working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am not getting any errors but it is not running correctly. The bit of code highlighted with `# **` is where it is going wrong. So when I run it, whether I put in .com or .co.uk or .org.uk or not it always ends up printing that my code is invalid.

```
import time
#Imports the time library.

#3
#Email validator
#Make a program to check whether an email address is valid or not.
#You could make sure that there are no spaces, that there is an @ symbol and a dot somewhere after it. Also check that the end parts of the address are not blank.
#Extensions:
#1. When an email address is found to be invalid, tell the user exactly what they did wrong with their email address rather than just saying it is invalid
#2. Allow the user to choose to give a text file with a list of email addresses and have it process them all automatically.


print("Only .com or .co.uk or .org.uk are accepted.")
def ev():
    #starts the definition and defines the command.
    time.sleep(1)
    #1 second wait
    email = input("Email: ")
    dot = "."
    at = "@"
    space = " "
    com = ".com"
    couk = ".co.uk"
    org = ".org.uk"
    if at not in email:
        print("Invalid. There is no @ in your email.")
        #Says email is invalid as there is no @
        ev()
    elif dot not in email:
        print("Invalid. There is no .(dot) in your email.")
        #Says email is invalid as there is no .
        ev()
        #Loops to asking for the email again
    elif space in email:
        print("Invalid. There shouldn't be any spaces in your email.")
        #Says email is invalid as there is a space
        ev()
        #Loops to asking for the email again
    elif com not in email or couk not in email or org not in email:  # **
        print("This email is not valid. Only .com or .co.uk or .org.uk are accepted.")**
        ev()
        #Loops to asking for the email again
    else:
        print("Valid!")

ev()
#Ends the definition so it starts automatically.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add at the the error message verbatim or better yet the whole backtrace. Just saying "isn't working" and "my code is invalid" are too vague.

Comment: The answers may have solved your initial concern, but it'd be a lot easier (and error-proof, unlike the current code) to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: You have an answer, but let's also point out that a regular expression would be more effective. Also it'd be good to organize this as a validator function that takes a string and returns an error message -- you could easily write unit tests for that -- and a separate function that reads input, calls the validitor, prints the result, and loops.

Comment: thnx for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `and` instead of `or`:

Try this:

```
 elif com not in email and couk not in email and org not in email:
    print("This email is not valid. Only .com or .co.uk or .org.uk are accepted.")**
    ev()
    #Loops to asking for the email again
```

Comment: Thnx! Works perfectly now!